# extract a string from a line using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

I have couple of lines like these as a part of a file

```
the jdbc:mondrian:DataSource=abcd_datasource
the jdbc:mondrian:DataSource=efgh_datasource
the jdbc:mondrian:DataSource=hijk_datasource
the jdbc:mondrian:DataSource=lmno_datasource
```

I want to extract the strings 
'abcd','efgh','hijk','lmno'

How to extract them? This is what I have tried so far:-

```
datasource_delimiter="_datasource"

logFileName=${1}


errorLogLines=($(grep -i "_datasource" $logFileName))

  for errorLogLine in ${errorLogLines[@]}
  do
    if [[ "$errorLogLine"~="jdbc:mondrian:DataSource=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)_datasource"  ]]
    then
      # what should I put here?
    fi
  done
```

Thanks

Comment: BTW, why the `-i` in the grep? Your regex requires `_datasource` to be lowercase elsewhere, so making it case-insensitive in the first-pass filter doesn't buy much.

Comment: BTW, while one of the linked question's answers suggests `expr`, that's very bad form (not actually built into bash, much slower than using a builtin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
logFileName=$1

datasource_re='jdbc:mondrian:DataSource=([[:alnum:]]+)_datasource'
while read -r errorLogLine; do
  if [[ "$errorLogLine" =~ $datasource_re ]]; then
    echo "Found source: ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  fi
done < <(grep -i "_datasource" "$logFileName")
```

---

Note:

- The quoting and spacing in `[[ "$var" =~ $regex ]]` is very deliberate.

  - You **must** have spaces surrounding the operators.
  - You **must not** quote the right-hand side if you want it to be parsed as a regex rather than a literal string.
- [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001): *How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?*
- [Why you don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)
- [BashPitfalls #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_....29_.29), on why `array=( $(...) )` is bad form.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `grep` you can do this:

```
grep -ioP 'DataSource=\K[a-z\d]+' file
```

```
abcd
efgh
hijk
lmno
```

If you don't have GNU `grep` then use this `sed`:

```
sed 's/.*DataSource=\([a-zA-Z0-9]*\).*/\1/' file
```

Comment: This is only conditionally available as part of GNU grep -- the libpcre dependency is a compile-time flag.

Answer (score 0):

You also could a simple awk one-liner as follows:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="DataSource=|_datasource"}{print $2}' file
```

output:

```
abcd
efgh
hijk
lmno
```

Hope that helps!